# Import facebook sdk android 4, class errors

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

I need to import facebook android sdk 4 (the lastest version) on eclipse, but i have some problems.
In fact some SDK classe can't found the sequent classes

- AppLink
- Continuation
- Task
- AppLinkResolver

what's wrong?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29302087/android-facebook-sdk-v4-0-not-working/29353219#29353219

Comment: Check, if you have import it properly - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379890/android-facebook-sdk-4-in-eclipse/29400310#29400310