# Can't import facebook-sdk to eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook-sdk-4.0

Hello everybody I imported the sdk but 324 errors apper
look at them:

```
    Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
    AppLink cannot be resolved to a type    FacebookAppLinkResolver.java    ‪/facebook/src/com/facebook/applinks‬   line 66 Java Problem
    Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
    DialogFragment cannot be resolved to a type FacebookDialogFragment.java ‪/facebook/src/com/facebook/internal‬   line 118    Java Problem
    Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
    Fragment cannot be resolved to a type   AppInviteDialog.java    ‪/facebook/src/com/facebook/share/widget‬   line 135    Java Problem
    Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
    FragmentActivity cannot be resolved to a type   FacebookActivity.java   ‪/facebook/src/com/facebook‬    line 57 Java Problem
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
'<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7 CallbackManagerImpl.java    ‪/facebook/src/com/facebook/internal‬   line 37 Java Problem
```

Comment: make sure that the path location of your facebook sdk and your adt should be in the same folder

Comment: how can i know where my adt is?

Comment: Go to Window-->Prefrences-->Android-->SDK Location

Comment: Please, take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379890/android-facebook-sdk-4-in-eclipse/29400310#29400310), that solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

After importing sdk create a lib file and place the android-support-v4.jar file in it .Problem is in facebook sdk android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment is used instead of android.app.Fragment

Answer (score 0):

Make sure path of facebook sdk and adt is same,plus import latest `google-play-services` library in your workspace.

Comment: how can i know what the path of the adt is?

Comment: find `eclipse.exe` file,the root folder of this file is the path of your adt

Comment: which folder? the full sdk folder or only the folder that's now in the workspace?

Comment: thank you for everything but I really need the last answer.. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Go in File > Import > Android (Existing code in WorkSpace > Browse For SDK > Check Copy project in workspace > Hit Enter Finish