# How to import facebook sdk, version 4.2.0 in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook-sdk-4.0

When I follow the android sdk steps of facebook developers website, I can not find the

> `build.gradle`
>   in eclipse.

That make me stop in this step.
Can someone help me to find this file with the details?

Or can anybody tell me how to add facebook sdk in eclipse?

Please.Thank you.

Comment: You should try to search at first - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379890/android-facebook-sdk-4-in-eclipse/29400310#29400310

Comment: Thanks for tell me the details of import facebook sdk from your link. Now I can continue to add the facebook in my Android app. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import the new Facebook SDK you should it from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android

-Then when you download it, copy the following folder to your proyect directory:
facebook

-Import the proyect to your workspace.

-Add the Facebook SDK as Library in eclipse. Right Click on your proyect-->properties--> Android and add it as library.

Thats all!

Comment: When I import facebook sdk, there have many error in src folder. Please tell me how to debug the error? Thanks.

Comment: According to your step, my project directory is mean the project which in the workplace?

Comment: Hi Ka, do you have java version 1.7 or later? I mean in the same folder where you have your proyect, for ex. Your app name is KaTest, and you have it in the folder KaProyects, so you have to copy the facebook proyect inside KaProyects. So it will be like this if you run the command "ls" inside KaProyect: facebook , KaTest