# Facebook login button crash

Tags: android, facebook

I did all steps from [Android Facebook SDK 4 in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379890/android-facebook-sdk-4-in-eclipse) and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#login_share

My activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    LoginButton loginButton;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");


        // Callback registration
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
            }
        });    


        final Button but_nova_hra = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nova_hra);
        but_nova_hra.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent obrazovkaHry = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HraActivity.class);
                startActivity(obrazovkaHry);
            }
        });

        final Button but_koniec = (Button) findViewById(R.id.konec);
        but_koniec.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

App crashes during start with

> Could not find com.facebook.FacebookActivity referenced from method com.facebook.internal.Validate.hasFacebookActivity

Where can the problem be?

**EDIT:** Just created new blank app with completly same settings and FacebookSdk.sdkInitializing passed sucessfully. There have to be some problem with this specific application, but where ? Both of them have same settings ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LoL, I just solved my problem. In the activity layout needs to be

> tools:context="com.kajmus.appname.MainActivity"

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to declare `FacebookActivity` in your manifest file like this

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
          android:configChanges=
                 "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
          android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Its [mentioned here..](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started)

Comment: I have it declared, same as    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/> and internet permission.