# Facebook SDK eclipse error

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook

I've followed the step by step instructions on importing the fb SDK according to [Android Facebook SDK 4 in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379890/android-facebook-sdk-4-in-eclipse) but the facebook project is still marked as having an error while there are no errors on the packages or resources folders as shown [image: no other errors] Can anyone help me on how to solve this problem

Comment: can you please right click on facebook project- prop - java build path and make sure there is no error there

Comment: there isn't any error

Comment: ok when you try to build your app is there is any problem showing in problem tab ?

Comment: Oh, yeah! it says 
Using 1.7 requires compiling with Android 4.4 (KitKat); currently using API 10 facebook  line 1 Android ADT Problem

Comment: ok you using android 2.3.3 chaange it to 4.4 if you have it or change JDK to 1.6 instead of 1.7

Comment: Can't believe that's all I was missing! It's alright now, thanks!!!!

Comment: anytime glad I could help :)