# How to Import Facebook SDK to Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am working on a project in eclipse. Since now it's the of the project and I want to import The Facebook SDK now. I have no experience with Android Studio. So import it like other project and face a bundles of error. I resolved many of them. Since now one error is still stuck me. that is in

**import android.support.annotation.Nullable;**

and the error is

**"The import android.support.annotation cannot be resolved"**

***My target Android SDK is "4.4.2" and Facebook SDK is "4.5.1"
Please Help me to resolve this without switching to Android Studio.***

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379890/android-facebook-sdk-4-in-eclipse

Comment: I already did this, it solve some of the problem. And the problem i face is not solved in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to include the annotations.jar file into your project, but note that there are two annotations.jar files in your Android SDK:

android-sdk/tools/support/annotations.jar - Which includes the following annotations:

SupportLint

TargetApi

android-sdk/extras/android/support/annotations/annotations.jar - Which includes many other annotations:

AnimRes

AnimatorRes

AnyRes

ArrayRes

AttrRes

BoolRes

ColorRes

DimenRes

DrawableRes

FractionRes

IdRes

IntDef

IntegerRes

InterpolatorRes

LayoutRes

MenuRes

**NonNull
Nullable**

PluralsRes

RawRes

StringDef

StringRes

StyleRes

StyleableRes

XmlRes

You need to import second one as the highlited is lies in second list.