# Using Facebook Android library from Maven Central

Tags: android, facebook, maven, android-support-library

I am trying to use `com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.1` in my Android Maven build.

From its [pom](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/3.23.1/facebook-android-sdk-3.23.1.pom) we can see that it depends on `com.android.support:support-v4`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
    <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
    <version>[21,22)</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

When I install the `support-v4` library using `maven-android-sdk-deployer`, the library is installed as `aar`.  However, Maven defaults to looking for the `jar`, and I get this error message:

```
Failed to collect dependencies at 
com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:aar:3.23.1 -> 
com.android.support:support-v4:jar:[21,22): No versions available for 
com.android.support:support-v4:jar:[21,22) within specified range -> [Help 1]
```

How are people managing to use the Maven versions of this Facebook library in their projects?  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29379890/64505) suggests just using the framework source in your project, can't we do better?

Comment: Sorry mistaken. The problem is that `com.android.support:support-v4:jar` [does not exist in Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.android.support%22%20a%3A%22support-v4%22)

Comment: No that is not the problem.  Android jars are installed to local maven repo using `maven-android-sdk-deployer`, but for com.android.support:support-v4 it installs `aar`, not `jar`.