# Android: Import facebook sdk 4.10.1 in eclipse

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, android-facebook

I am developing an application in which i want to share some content to Facebook. For which i need to use Facebook sdk. I gone through the [This Link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android)

I downloaded the latest SDK from facebook site as facebook-android-sdk-4.10.1.

According to the steps i am tring to import that but not able to do that. The import is [image]

But according to the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379890/android-facebook-sdk-4-in-eclipse)
 i need to select Facebook which is not there.

What i am missing or where i am wrong please suggest me.

Comment: If you down vote question no problem, But atleast let me know why it gets down voted.

Comment: **May be this is a repetitive question and a silly one.**

Comment: **Exact duplicate of** [Android Facebook SDK 4 in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379890/android-facebook-sdk-4-in-eclipse)

Comment: @Aaron Gillion Answer on the above link is not working. Thats why i posted question.

Answer (score 0):

This is also my problem. As far as i know the current Facebook SDK 4.10.1 is custom made to be extracted to android studio thats why you cannot see the Facebook folder. If you try to look in your file explorer you would see "facebook-android-sdk-4.10.1.aar" inside the facebook folder. Try searching ways to convert it to jar (aar->jar) so it can be read by eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29400310/3820010 but use the 4.5 or 4.6 SDK. Newer versions won't work with that method.