# How to get latest facebook-sdk version for android?

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am working on facebook integration in app using eclipse IDE.so, can any body suggest me latest facebook sdk download link.so, i can import sdk into eclipse.

***Your answer would be appreciated***

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads check this url, you get the latest facebook sdks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can download latest SDK [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads).

Comment: there is not any facebook sdk for eclipse.

Comment: can you give me link for facebooksdk-eclipse?

Comment: I belive there is no such thing, but take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379890/android-facebook-sdk-4-in-eclipse

Comment: very clear,I want facebook sdk which i can integrate easily with eclipse IDE.

Comment: This cannot be true. Last SDK right now is 4.42 (20 days ago), but that page only lists up to 4.41.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import facebook sdk 4.0 to eclipse,follow the steps in this [Android Facebook SDK 4 in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379890/android-facebook-sdk-4-in-eclipse)