# Facebook SDK for api level 12

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I want to use Login with Facebook feature in my android app. As per documentation here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android, It requires API Level 15 but I want to support it from API 12.
Is there anyway to support it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to build the Login manually, it is explained in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow

The SDK requires API Level 15 though, as you found out. You can´t use the SDK if you want to support older versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Facebook's [download page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads), they have links for legacy SDKs. I believe you're looking for versions < 4.5.1. You can check their [change log](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/change-log-4.x) to make sure.

Comment: I found one good answer but I can't see facebook folder in it. Please have a look in http://stackoverflow.com/a/29400310/3234665

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a lower version of Facebook SDK. Probably less than 4.6.0.

Check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading-4.x#450to451