# integrating facebook login in my android app

Tags: facebook-android-sdk

I have eclipse kepler version.I downloaded facebook android sdk version4.16.0 from developers/facebook website.Download is successful.But if i try to import the facebook project into my android app,the facebook project is not listed.But only two sample projects are listed.Can somebody please help me.

Comment: I'd recommend you to use [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) and now it's official Android App Development IDE.

Comment: Sorry. I can't use Android Studio now, as I have already developed my app in eclipse. Any idea why facebook is not being listed as a project when I say 'Import Projects'?

Comment: You can convert/import Eclipse project into Android Studio. And importing Facebook SDK is far better in Android Studio than Eclipse as stated [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads/). Still if you want to use Eclipse check this Stackoverflow [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379890/android-facebook-sdk-4-in-eclipse) which clearly explains steps to import Facebook SDK.

Comment: Thanks Shashanth. Finally, I was able to do it in eclipse itself by installing facebook sdk version 4.0.0. May be the problem I was facing was because of incompatibility.