# Error Importing Facebook SDK For Android In Eclipse

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I'm facing problem while importing facebook SDK for android in Eclipse. When I import, it shows a lot of errors.

Please help me solve this problem

[image]

Comment: After clean build? See some of the Errors by expanding in Problems tab.

Comment: possible duplicate of [android facebook sdk v4.0 not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29302087/android-facebook-sdk-v4-0-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

The Facebook Android SDK v4.0 uses Gradle as it's build and dependency management system. http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle-integration-eclipse-44 is available for Eclipse. Also http://eclipse.org/m2e/ can be used for integrating with the Facebook's maven artifact: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|com.facebook.android|facebook-android-sdk|4.0.0|