# Facebook sdk syntax error while importing into eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I've downloaded the sdk from the [github](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk) and imported the **facebook** project into my eclipse workspace which I want to it to my project's libraries but when I import the facebook project it contains some syntax error such as

```
ArrayList<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<>();
```

or the **R** is not found ... What can I do to fix this ?

These are the few errors I get after importing facebook project:

```
getTokenClient = new GetTokenClient(loginClient.getActivity(), // on get activity function
```

or

```
public LoginClient(Fragment fragment) { // on type Fragment
    this.fragment = fragment;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [android facebook sdk v4.0 not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29302087/android-facebook-sdk-v4-0-not-working)

Comment: New android sdk uses gradle so you cant import it as usual android project. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29302087/android-facebook-sdk-v4-0-not-working or you can see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379890/android-facebook-sdk-4-in-eclipse

Comment: There are some active issues with Eclipse. Recommend updating to IntelliJ or better yet, Android Studio, and use Gradle build files to handle dependencies.